# Strange compilation error after I upgrade to Xcode-beta 7

Tags: ios, swift

Here is my code.

```
        var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell)
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation:.Automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

I got the following compile error:

> Use of unresolved identifier 'Automatic'

I tried UITableViewAnimation.Automatic. But failed too.

What's wrong with it? Thanks.

Comment: Try `UITableViewRowAnimation. Automatic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading.
In Xcode 6 beta 7, `indexPathForCell()` returns an *optional*, so you have to unwrap
it or use a conditional assignment:

```
if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) {
    self.tableView.beginUpdates()
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
    self.tableView.endUpdates()
}
```

(Note that calling `begin/EndUpdates` is not really necessary if only a single row
is updated.)